# 'function' object has no attribute 'objects' Django AttributeError

Tags: django

This is my models:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    body = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

and this is my views in django

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import post
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.
def post(request, id):
    data = {'post': post.objects.get(id=id)}
    return render(request, 'post/post.html', data)
```

I try to get post by id but error found:

```
AttributeError at /post/3/
'function' object has no attribute 'objects'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because your function name is also `post` so django confused.

so change your view function name `post` to `postView`.

Answer (score 1):

Class and Models start with upper case letters. In this case, Django is confusing your model Post with the function post.

An examplo of how do it more clearly:

```
>>> from blog.models import Blog, Entry
>>> entry = Entry.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> cheese_blog = Blog.objects.get(name="Cheddar Talk")
>>> entry.blog = cheese_blog
>>> entry.save()
```